# Java applet in HTML. JAR execution

Tags: java, html, class, jar, applet

Lets say we have this kind of Java applet placed in HTML page.

```html
<applet code="test.class" archive="test_archive.jar"></applet>
```

Is it possible that WEB browser will execute "test_archive.jar" file even then class file "test.class" was not reachable (resulted in HTTP 404)?
Also, is it possible to code Java applet in HTML page that only jar file would be needed to execute it in WEB browser?

Comment: I will ask the same from another perspective. Lets say dummy user A presses on every popup which appears while he browses the Internet. Bad actor B creates and signs Java archive "test_archive.jar" containing a trojan, then places it in some HTML page. But B made a mistake and mistyped .class file name in HTML applet tag so user's A browser didn't pulled this .class file (JAR archive was downloaded successful). Question, is here is any possibility that Java archive will be executed without .class file?

Comment: 1) Is `test.class` ***inside*** `test_archive.jar`? 2) *"Also, is it possible to code Java applet in HTML page that only jar file would be needed to execute it in WEB browser?"*  I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.  If the applet is inside the Jar, then yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here is applet tag code you coan put in web page which one load YourApplet
// Remember when you try to access your applet out side your system then YourApplet should be digitally signed
<APPLET code="YourApplet.class" archive="YourApplet.jar"  codebase="http://www.example.com/yourbase_directory_where_YourApplet.jar_file_exits/" width=250 height=150>
when applet load from this location it is use the codebase directory
```